# Backup and Restore option not available in pgAdmin III

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, pgadmin, pg-restore

I have to take backup of my database but when I right click DB and then backup  The button for backup is disabled. Similarly in existing database ,not able to restore because the Restore button too disabled. 
I was working fine till the time I created a new database.

How do they get enabled?

Comment: At a guess you probably aren't connected as a superuser. Hard to be sure.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem in ubuntu 14.04. It was necessary to install both postgresql-client-common (which contains pg_dump and pg_restore) **and** postgresql-client packages.

Comment: on Fedora, this will install pd_dump and pg_restore: sudo dnf install postgresql

Comment: Using nixos/nixpkgs also just had to install the server+client (to get psql I assume): `nix-env -iA nixos.postgresql `

Comment: `This wrked for Linux Mint.

Answer (score 10):

There is no need for reinstall,
just open File->Options->Binary paths and add set "PG bin path" to path where pg_dump/pg_restore is located.
[image: pg_dump/pg_restore paths]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution:

```
$ yum install postgresql-contrib
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem could be caused by a fact that you simply do not have pg_dump and pg_restore tools installed (or they are not visible for pgadmin).

This had happen to me when installing pgadmin3 on CentOS 7 via [PostgreSQL yum repository](http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php). To resolve this I had to install package with those tools - in my case postgresql94 (PostgreSQL client programs and libraries).

On other distros you will need to find which package should be installed. AFAIK this issue is not present in Windows environment, pgadmin installer probably have all needed dependencies.

Comment: I have pg_restore installed (version 9.3.9) with psql version 9.4.4. Just installed pgadmin 1.20.0, and the restore button is also disabled. Read somewhere that pgadmin may not know how to read a plain (text) dumpfile, how can it be?

Comment: @Rodrigo Disabled state of restore button, rather is not connected with dump file type - as I understand you're not able to use it. If you have plain sql script and it is not very big, you should be able to open it in query window and run (maybe with some adjustments). Additionally as other comment stated - maybe your user doesn't have required role?

Comment: This solved it for me: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13586/70100. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing problem in restoring my database from backup, so I followed some steps:

1. Go to c:\ drive and find this path "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin"
2. Copy all the files from there then
3. past all the copied files to the given folder
   "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\runtime"

Your problem will definitely be solved.

You can go and check my video Where I showed step by step problem.

***[link]
(https://youtu.be/GS3Dg0TfyFI)***

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall your PGAdmin3.

We had the same problem on a Mac and after reinstallation, the right click menu showed more options like "Restore" and "Backup".

Comment: unfortunately I reinstalled and I did not solve it. I ended up using pg_restore on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue (restore button disabled) and the problem was a corrupted dump.

So, I've created a new dump and tried again. After selecting the new file, the button became available.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i'm on windows,

if python isn't installed, install it.

restart, and you're done.

Comment: Are you sure? it worked. Postgres is actually wriiten in C++

Comment: Hello @DmanCannon, that time i was facing issue regarding python, that's why I shared my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked in the pgadmin4 sql:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions;
```

and got the current installed 2.1 which is not correct. You need to check on the db command line, the same query did result that the adminpack is NOT installed.

Solution: Logon to the DB on comand line and write

```
CREATE EXTENSION adminpack;
```